# How does Islam justify non-guided people going to hell and what is the point of free will if the future is already written?

Tags: non-muslim, jahannam, free-will, qadar

We are all Muslims because we are either raised up as Muslims or at some point in life reverted to Islam. But what about others, the ones who are not being guided is it just their fault that they have not become Muslims. They would have done what the Islam teaches them to do if they had been guided and it is said that those who have not accepted Islam will go to jahannam. So how is this justified?

Also, we know that the future is already written and if it's already written what's the point of free will?

Comment: We do have free will, it is is destined what we would do so we can choose something by free will and that action would be destined.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. This known as the [fate of the unlearned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate_of_the_unlearned). It exists in two forms: for [people living before the revelation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpA4ZIw6vrI), and for [people living after the revelation but isolated from it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSdGr4K4qLg). Many different answers exist depending on religions, schisms and people within these religions. You can however see "categories" of answers, regardless of the details of each doctrine. For Islam (and most religions), the answers can be summed up by:

   - there are no unlearned, since god supplied a sufficient amount of prophets, or made enough people spread the faith. This applies only to current unlearned.
   - some unlearned go to heaven, but it would have helped if they learned
   - they burn in hell forever (which may not be the first thing to mention when trying to teach them)
   - they are judged on their actions independently from their faith (which can be problematic, since it gives [no incentive to believe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atheist's_Wager))

Apparently, there is no consensus on this within Islam.

2. "we know that the future is already written" is a little vague. It does not specify if you are speaking about a fully deterministic world, or a broader future written event (like some final apocalypse that will happen whatever you do)

This is a problem that is not inherent to Islam. In a purely deterministic world, there would be no free will. Our thoughts would be triggered by one another, by our environment, by some [other spiritual influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_plane)... Even with less determinism, the idea that we are largely (or entirely) the product of external forces (divine or not) is quite challenging to the concept of person as we know it.

In pratice, not many people seriously consider this idea since it [removes responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_responsibility#Hard_determinism). Furthermore, even if it were true, it would still be completely unpractical (your brain is too complex, we are absolutely unable to predict what your next thought will be). So we might just consider some kind of free will regardless of its validity, at least for our justice systems which are based on it.

Comment: "In pratice, not many people seriously consider this idea since it removes responsibility." Both false; determinism is a major current in modern philosophy, physics, and neuroscience. It also doesn't remove responsibility in any societally relevant sense; it just removes the concept of blame as in "I despise you for freely authoring this", but responsibility as in "this person caused that" is not removed at all, and with some minor rethinking, modern law, social norms, and interpersonal relationships as they are pretty much anywhere remain fully intact. You'll even get less hatred out of it.